# Does the browser pass the name of the camera being used to the website

Tags: web-browser, web-service, video

Does the browser pass the name of the camera being used to the website which is accessing our camera like when we use **obs** virtual cam so is the website able to detect that a virtual camera is being used?

Comment: It will depend on the client and the protocol used. I know that you are concerned about privacy, but this technical question isn't about security. The answer might impact privacy incidentally, but it, itself, is not about security.

Comment: Although the question is closed - have a look at the API used to access webcams: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo

Apparently the device label (such as FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)) is passed if the user has granted persistent permission to use the device.

Comment: yeah. I checked the navigator API which is used to list the devices available and using that the server can check the device used for sending the video or audio stream.
So if we use a virtual camera the name of the virtual camera is passed.